# 2 Threads, Irc connection on second thread, want first thread to tell thread to send a message

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, irc, python-multithreading

So I am writting a irc chat bot with a pygtk gui. This bot has its gui running on a loop in the main script. When I press a button on the gui it starts a thread wich opens a socket and connect to a irc channel, when I press it again it pauses the thread, and when I press it yet again it resumes the thread.

Until here all good.

But I want it to when I press a button in the gui (main loop) to read a text box and tell the thread to send the text trough the irc connection.

My problem is I can't get the main loop to tell the thread to send the text. I tried something like(to test it out):

```
def botSendMessage(button):
    thread.sendMessage(irc, "test")

handlers = {
"on_bot_send_button_clicked": botSendMessage,

}
builder.connect_signals(handlers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was alredy able to achieve what I was looking for. I used global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Queue object that is available in both threads (passed in at creation time) to pass messages between them.

In the main loop of the irc thread, do a nonblocking check for items in the queue that need to be sent.